# How to implement Bootstrap classes to Vue-Formulate?

Tags: bootstrap-4, vuejs2, vue-formulate

According to [Vue Formulate](https://vueformulate.com/), you can add Bootstrap to it:

> With provided class props you can add your own set of style classes globally or on a case-by-case basis. Tailwind? No problem. **Bootstrap? You're covered**. Roll your own? Right on, it’s supported.

OK, so how do you do it?

I tried like so and it did not work:

```
<FormulateInput
  type="email"
  class="form-control" <------bootstrap class
  label="What is your school email address?"
  validation="bail|required|email|ends_with:.edu"
  validation-name="School email"
  placeholder="user@university.edu"
/>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it says in the [Vue Formulate documentation](https://vueformulate.com/guide/theming/customizing-classes):

*Changing classes on a given input is easy. Simply target the class key you’d like to change with a prop named* `[element class key]-class`. *To target a state use* `[element class key]-[state class key]-class`.
`
And having the
[image]

In the [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#form-controls):

### *Form controls*

*Textual form controls—like `<input>s`, `<select>s`, and `<textarea>s`—are styled with the `.form-control` class. Included are styles for general appearance, focus state, sizing, and more.*

This means what you are targeting there is the `input`.

This way you should try:

```
<FormulateInput
  type="email"
  input-class="form-control"
  label="What is your school email address?"
  validation="bail|required|email|ends_with:.edu"
  validation-name="School email"
  placeholder="user@university.edu"
/>
```

You can also add the validation bootstrap classes by adding properties:

```
input-is-valid-class="valid-feedback"
input-has-errors-class="invalid-feedback"
```

Comment: thanks. I will investigate and report back to you if all is well!

Comment: That works great, however, adding the validation bootstrap classes seems to cause an issue that hides the input field. But other than that, thank you! helps me.

Answer (score 9):

I used the following to **globally** match Vue Formulate (2.5) applied styles to Bootstrap 4:

```
Vue.use(VueFormulate, {
    classes: {
        outer: 'form-group',
        input: 'form-control',
        inputHasErrors: 'is-invalid',
        help: 'form-text text-muted',
        errors: 'list-unstyled text-danger'
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `input-class` or `element-class` instead of the `class` attribute. You can also customize the classes globally. For more information, please read the chapter about [customizing classes](https://vueformulate.com/guide/theming/customizing-classes) in the Vue Formulate documentation.